# bs4 - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' when search has no results

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I am using Beautifulsoup to filter data from a website. To do this, I pass several search terms in a loop using the site's built-in search box.

If the search term does not find any content, the following loop in soup breaks.

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25352/1005464644.py in <cell line: 10>()
     21 
     22         soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
---> 23         results = soup.find('ul', {'class':'result-list'}).find_all('li')
     24 
     25         for i in results:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Because no data was found, logically no data could be transferred to the soup.

How can I catch this error?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
# Imports

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

ausschreibungsliste = []


sb_1 = ['66512200', '85140000',  '75000000', '75130000', '75131000',  '79200000' , '79210000' , '79510000']

for z in sb_1:
    
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get('https://www.service.bund.de/Content/DE/Ausschreibungen/Suche/Formular.html')
    was_sb1 = driver.find_element("xpath", '//input[@id="f4641464d4642144"]')
    was_sb1.send_keys(z)
    was_sb1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    while True:



        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        results = soup.find('ul', {'class':'result-list'}).find_all('li')

        for i in results:   

            # Liste erzeugen
            
            # Ausschreibung
            ausschreibung = i.find_all('h3')[0].get_text().strip().replace(u'Ausschreibung', u'').replace(u'\xad', u'')

            # Vergabestelle
            organisation = i.find_all('p')[0].get_text().strip().replace(u'Vergabestelle ', u'')

            # Ausschreibungsdatum
            verdatum = i.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip().replace(u'Veröffentlicht ', u'')

            # Frist
            frist = i.find_all('p')[2].get_text().replace(u'Angebotsfrist ', u'')

            # Typ
            typ = 'Ausschreibung'

            # Website
            website = 'service.bund.de'

            # Prüfung ab
            pruefdatum_format = 'fehlt'

            # Datei erzeugt
            jetzt = 'fehlt'

            i_info = {
                            'Vergabedatum': verdatum,
                            'Frist':  frist,
                            'Organisation': organisation,
                            'Ausschreibung': ausschreibung,
                            'Typ': typ,
                            'Website': website,
                            'Prüfung ab': pruefdatum_format,
                            'Datei erzeugt': jetzt
                                        
                            
                        }
                        
            ausschreibungsliste.append(i_info)

            
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        
                
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
```

Comment: Check the result of `find` before calling `findall`.

Comment: I am still quite a beginner. Can you give me a tip on how to do this?

Comment: Which part: getting the result of `find`, checking it, or using it to call `findall`?

Comment: I think I need to jump directly to the next search term if the search result has no hits, and not jump into the soup procedure.
In Basic, the search term loop would have been written:
if <noresult> next <search term>.
I don't know how to approach this though.

Comment: You can use 'try' and 'except' statements. here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: So you might want to read up on `continue`.

Comment: I read through the documentation and work deeper into try.

Comment: Oh, and continue. I now understood that this is a command.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines like:

```
if soup.find('ul', {'class':'result-list'}):
    results = soup.find('ul', {'class':'result-list'}).find_all('li')

        for i in results:   
            etc.
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution based on the comments of Scott Hunter and AudioBaten.

Here is the (shortened) code:

```
ausschreibungsliste = []

# CPV-Codes die zu suchen sind

cpvcode = ['32441300', '64226000' , '66512200']

  
for z in cpvcode:
    
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get('the_url')
    suchfeld = driver.find_element("xpath", '//input[@id="f4641464d4642144"]')
    suchfeld.clear()
    suchfeld.send_keys(z)
    suchfeld.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    try:

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        results = soup.find('ul', {'class':'result-list'}).find_all('li')

        while True:
            
            for i in results:   

                # Liste erzeugen
                
                .... etc. ....

                i_info = {
                                'Vergabedatum': verdatum,
                                'Frist':  frist,
                                'Organisation': organisation,
                                'Ausschreibung': ausschreibung,
                                'CPV-Code': z,
                                'Link': linkausschreibung,
                                'Typ': typ,
                                'Website': website,
                                'Prüfung ab': pruefdatum_format,
                                'Datei erzeugt': jetzt
                                            
                                
                            }
                            
                ausschreibungsliste.append(i_info)

            # Nächster Seitenaufruf bis letzte Seite erreicht
            if not soup.select_one('span', {'class':'disabled'}):
                next=driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="main"]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
            else:
                print('Ausschreibungen gefunden :', len(ausschreibungsliste))
                break
    except:
        continue
```

Thanks for your help.